# Flowtype Warning: This module only has a default export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have a `utils/index.js` file which looks something like this to give me quick access to all the utils within my app.

```
/**
 * @providesModule utils
 * @flow
 */

import isValidEmail from './isValidEmail';
import isWithinVersionRange from './isWithinVersionRange';

...more util functions

export {
  isValidEmail,
  isWithinVersionRange,
}
```

When I import one of these functions in another file like so...

`import { isValidEmail } from 'utils';`

Flow throws a warning saying `This module only has a default export`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nah, looks like a problem in flow for me.

Comment: @Bergi I'll throw up an issue on flowtype github then, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my flow import to a capital and all references to it to a capital:

```
/**
 * @providesModule Utils
 * @flow
 */
```

And then did a find and replace for all `'utils'` -> `'Utils'`

```
import { isValidEmail, isWithinVersionRange } from 'Utils';
```

Then my flow errors were gone and our functions were properly flow typed.

If someone knows **why**, that'd interesting. But here's the fix.